# Instead of passing whole array to intent pass only onClicked value

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent

I am trying to pass only the onClicked value in the below code instead of passing the whole array to intent. Is it possible??

Here, i am sending whole array as in `i.putExtra("rank", rank)`, is there some other way.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };

    country = new String[] { "China", "India", "United States",
            "Indonesia", "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh",
            "Russia", "Japan" };

    population = new String[] { "2,000,000,000", "1,500,000,000",
            "123,123,123", "123,123,123", "123,123,123", "123,123,123",
            "123,123,123", "123,123,123", "123,123,123", "123,123,123" };

    flag = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india,
            R.drawable.unitedstates, R.drawable.indonesia,
            R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.pakistan, R.drawable.nigeria,
            R.drawable.bangladesh, R.drawable.russia, R.drawable.japan };

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, rank, country, population, flag);

    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);

            i.putExtra("rank", rank);
            i.putExtra("country", country);
            i.putExtra("population", population);
            i.putExtra("flag", flag);
            i.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `i.putExtra("rank", rank[position]);`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `position` value to uniquely identify the row clicked.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);
i.putExtra("rank", rank[position]);
i.putExtra("country", country[position]);
i.putExtra("population", population[position]);
i.putExtra("flag", flag[position]);
startActivity(i);
```